# Save memory dump edit into an exe file in OllyDbg

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg, memory-dump, dbg

I am editing the client of my game server at [Ollydbg](https://www.ollydbg.de/). The problem is that i don't know how to save it into a new .exe file.

I open my game and then open [Ollydbg](https://www.ollydbg.de/) and attach the game process to it.

I press ctrl+M and find the string that i want to change. It opens a “Dump” window with hex and the string.

After i edit the binary, how to save to an .exe file? Thanks!!

I tried to binary edit from memory dump and was expecting to be able to save it into a new .exe file. The option copy to executable never show up (i believe there should be another way)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using OllyDbg 2.01,

- Right click in the 'Cpu' view (the window with the instructions in it)
- 'Edit' -> 'Copy all modifications to executable'
- This opens a new window
- Right click in this new window
- 'Save file...'